# Upload a video via PHP and encode to MP4 and/or WebM on the server?

Tags: php, html5-video, mp4, encode, webm

I want to upload a file (Indeed, I already did it using PHP and JQuery) but I want to encode it to MP4 and/or WebM in the process of the upload, such as Youtube does when you upload a video there. Is there a option to be able to do it in the server during the process?

Do I have to encode them first and then upload?

Comment: You can certainly do this on the server. I would suggest using ffmpeg to do the work. See here https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Using%20FFmpeg%20from%20PHP%20scripts

Comment: PHP's upload mechanisms are stupid, and you cannot process the uploaded data as it's actually uploading. If you want to stream-process, you'll need to use non-PHP handlers.

Comment: Yeah that's why I mentioned, it doesn't matter when, in the process or after of it... But I finally got it!

Comment: @MarcB, do you know any language that can do this? Upload and convert at the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it at the end of file upload, which is after you moved the file to a specific location (below code)

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

You can use a free and well-known library called FFMPEG which supports a wide range of formats. Please take a look at these two links for example and better explanation:

[https://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Video-Conversion-With-FFMPEG.html](https://phpro.org/tutorials/Video-Conversion-With-FFMPEG.html)

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Using%20FFmpeg%20from%20PHP%20scripts

Basically, you can call the FFMPEG function from PHP like this

```
<?php

 /*** convert video to flash ***/
 exec("ffmpeg -i video.avi -ar 22050 -ab 32 -f flv -s 320x240 video.flv");

?>
```

Comment: Beware, PHP often has a maximum execution time set to 30s. On big videos, the time of transfer plus the transcode may easily overflow this delay and abort the process. If you've got your own server (it sure seems if you can use `ffmpeg`), you may want to use asynchronous workers to do the actual processing (have a look at [celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/), [sidekiq](http://sidekiq.org/) and similar software). I don't know about PHP integration though.